# Adding layer with date/time to video DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow

How to add layer with time in DirectShow? I get time in my source filter, and i want to show it in render window. 
Thanks.

Comment: Show some efforts. What have you tried so far? Post some code.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi I have graph with my pushsource filter, avi decompressor and render filter. I looking for simple way to show date/time in my window with video, may be it is complete filters or methods to do this. I didnt start working on this task, coz I didnt know the start vector. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the media type of the source filter?

One option is to draw it on RGB with e.g. gdi+. I wrote a framerate estimator filter that does that available in the [video processing project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/) with the source [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/videoprocessing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/videoprocessing/Source/Filters/DirectShow/FramerateDisplayFilter/FramerateDisplayFilter.cpp).

Comment: Thanks. Mediatype is Video, subtype is my own codec. Source filter parsing network stream and throw out frames that encoded with my codec and puted in AVI conteners. I know, its wrong, but its 
historically. After that I decompress AVI and throw frame to render filter.

Comment: I had explore your project. Its very helpful for me. May be you can advise me book or source for DS beginning. I want to know base thinks like how to send start information to filter. For example: ip address when I use tcp source, etc. Thanks

Comment: @fandyushin There is a DirectShow book by Mark Pesce, which you can search for. The samples in the SDK itself are very useful, you just have to know which sample to look at...Other than that the DS documentation on MSDN, and the MS DS forum are useful. WRT your question, search for IFileSourceFilter, which is the standard way of getting a URL or path into a source filter.